# Como definir e obter versão do aplicativo

Tags: android

Estou quase terminando meu primeiro app android, e eu fiz uma "pagina" de sobre e coloquei manualmente o numero da versão.
Da para definir a versão em algum local ? e tem como obter ela dentro do programa ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para recuperar a versão do app use:

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
String version = pInfo.versionName;

int verCode = pInfo.versionCode;
```

O jeito mais facil e rápido de alterar a versão no Android Studio é:

> Pressione SHIFT+CTRL+ALT+S
>
> Escolha a tab 'Flavors'
>
> Os dois ultimos campos são 'Version Code' e 'Version Name'

Mas você também pode alterar pelo arquivo `build.gradle`:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```